# Cypher - Aggregation with optional match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following node structure in database:

```
Artifact {id:'art1'}
|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1', value:1}
|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_2', value:2}
=Artifact {id:'art1_1'}
=|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_1', value:1}
=|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_2', value:2}
==Artifact {id:'art1_1_1'}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_1_1', value:1}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_1_2', value:2}
==Artifact {id:'art1_1_2'}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_2_1', value:1}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_2_2', value:2}
==Artifact {id:'art1_1_3'}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_3_1', value:1}
==|ArtifactProperty {key:'prop1_1_3_2', value:2}
```

Where an Artifact is a node that can be related to other Artifact nodes via a CURRENT relation and/or ArtifactProperties also via a CURRENT relation. The CURRENT relation holds the id of the root

My goal is to fetch all artifacts whith its children and properties.

The following request:

```
MATCH (a:Artifact)-[:CURRENT {root: 'art1'}]->(c:ArtifactProperty)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Artifact)-[:CURRENT {root: 'art1'}]->(b:Artifact) 
WITH a {.id, children: collect(b {.id}), properties: collect(c {.key, .value})} as mapped
return mapped.id, mapped.children, mapped.properties
```

Provides the following result:

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"mapped.id"│"mapped.children"                                                     │"mapped.properties"                                                   │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"art1_1"   │[{"id":"art1_1_3"},{"id":"art1_1_2"},{"id":"art1_1_1"},{"id":"art1_1_3│[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1"},{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1"},{"v│
│           │"},{"id":"art1_1_2"},{"id":"art1_1_1"}]                               │alue":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2"},{"value│
│           │                                                                      │":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2"}]           │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_1" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]                                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1"     │[{"id":"art1_1"},{"id":"art1_1"}]                                     │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_2"}]       │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_2" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]                                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_3" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]
```

The issue is my results are repeated for Artefacts with children (properties and children fields contain twice the same result).

There is probably a better way to perform this aggregation than to do an OPTIONAL MATCH so let me know if   I did not pick the best option.

EDIT:
This is the result I am trying to get, note that each child and property appear only once:

```
╒═══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"mapped.id"│"mapped.children"                                                     │"mapped.properties"                                                   │
╞═══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"art1_1"   │[{"id":"art1_1_3"},{"id":"art1_1_2"},{"id":"art1_1_1"}]               │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2"}    │
│           │                                                                      │                                                                      │
│           │                                                                      │                                                                      │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_1" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_1_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]                                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1"     │[{"id":"art1_1"}]                                                     │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_2"}]       │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_2" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]                                                                     │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"art1_1_3" │[]                                                                    │[{"value":1.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_1"},{"value":2.0,"key":"prop_1_1_2_2"}│
│           │                                                                      │]
```

Comment: what is the exact result you are looking for ? These types of questions are most probably best solved with a query with a variable pattern length.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what would you like to achieve. What does this mean?
The issue is my results are repeated for Artefacts with children (properties and children fields contain twice the same result)

Comment: Hello, I would like to fetch all Artifacts as {id: <id>, children: [<child artifact id1>, child artifact id2>, ...], properties: [<artifact property 1>, <artifact property 2>]}
I have added the result I'm trying to get in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [DISTINCT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-the-distinct-operator):

```
MATCH (a:Artifact)-[:CURRENT {root: 'art1'}]->(c:ArtifactProperty)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Artifact)-[:CURRENT {root: 'art1'}]->(b:Artifact) 
WITH a {
  .id, 
  children: collect(DISTINCT b {.id}), 
  properties: collect(DISTINCT c {.key, .value})
} AS mapped
RETURN mapped.id, mapped.children, mapped.properties
```

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for.